# How to replace multiple (non-unique) substrings in a string?

Tags: python, replace

I have this string -

```
test_str = 'hello_2Testsmthhello_1smthhello_1'
```

and I have a list of strings -

```
list1 = ['hello_1', 'hello_2']
```

Now I want to replace `hello_1` and `hello_2` with a period(`.`). This is what I've tried -

```
for i in list1:
    h = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")
#print (h)
```

This gives me the string - `.Testsmthhello_1smthhello_1`

However, the expected output is - `.Testsmth.smth.`

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Where you have written `h = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")`, do you expect this to change the value of `test_str`? Why or why not? If it doesn't change, then can you explain how you expect the loop to work?

Comment: In general, you should try to think about your code first, and step through the logic of it. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: Okay, so the first time through the loop, you do `h = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")`, so `h` ends up with the result of doing the first replacement, and `test_str` is the same as before. Right? So, what do you think will happen the second time through the loop, given that `test_str` didn't change? Again: *try to think about your code first, and step through the logic of it*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Thanks for your advice.. I didn't think of it that way..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the **h** in the loop to **test_str** :)

```
for i in list1:
    test_str = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")
```

In your original loop, you did successfully replace the substrings with **.** in **test_str** but you didn't save this change. **test_str** stayed the same and **h** got a brand new value in each loop. As you can see by printing the values during the loop.

```
for i in list1:
    print(i)
    h = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")
    print(h)
    print(test_str)
```

Hopefully I explained this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` returns a copy of the string with the replaced version so you need to assign it back to `test_str`:

```
test_str = 'hello_2Testsmthhello_1smthhello_1'
list1 = ['hello_1', 'hello_2']
for i in list1:
    test_str = test_str.replace(i, ".")
    
print(test_str) #.Testsmth.smth.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because test_str is replaced only once.
Do not use `h` for your intent.

```
for i in list1:
    test_str = test_str.replace(str(i), ".")
```

If you do not want to change test_str, then make a copy as follows.

```
import copy
h = copy.copy(test_str)

for i in list1:
    h = h.replace(str(i), ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` for it

```
import re

test_str = 'hello_2Testsmthhello_1smthhello_1'

pattern = r'hello_\d'

print(re.sub(pattern,'.', test_str))
```